# javascript timestamp insert into string Variable

Tags: javascript, html

First off, I have no programming experience, just enough to get me in trouble.  I was wondering if someone could write a line of code to add a numeric timestamp to an existing string varible on an HTML page.  the variable needs to create a semi random identifier by combining a static text element (SOP) with a time stamp:

```
map("orderNumber") = "SOP+TIMESTAMP"
```

Can anyone write it for me in a way that i can just paste it into an HTML page?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context around what you are trying to do? Are you sure time stamp is good enough or do you need a proper unique identifier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getTime()` method of the `Date` object to generate a timestamp, and then add it to the end of your static text element:

```
map("orderNumber") = "SOP" + (new Date().getTime())
```